# SQL : Query successful but no INSERT is done

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I've got an issue finding what's wrong with my insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO schema.table2(champ2)
SELECT table1.champ.1
FROM schema.table1, schema.table2
```

It often returns me "Query returned successfully" but with "INSERT 0 0".
How can I possibly **find the error** ?

NB: Some queries worked between these two tables. And sometimes the exact same ones return "INSERT 0 0". I'm just lost and pgadmin won't return me explanations..

Comment: SELECT table1.champ.1   too many dots.  FROM schema.table1, schema.table2  -looks very suspicious. It is CROSS JOIN. Do you really need it?

Comment: Furthermore, can you show us what the output of that cross join select actually is?

Comment: **Bad habits to kick** : [using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Do you **really** intend a cross join between those two tables? But in any case, the query would return nothing if at least one of the tables is empty. If nothing gets inserted, check the number of rows in both tables (`select count(*) from ...`)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show us the **real** query you are using. `SELECT table1.champ.1` is invalid SQL and would result in an error

Comment: this seems to be a very pale logic. Why would you select data into schema.table2 from schema.table2?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this post. Solution seems basic.

Adding "table2" in FROM (i.e. the table I'm inserting into) makes my select statement empty..

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

When it's failing to insert into **schema.table2(champ2)** please execute select part of the statement to know whether there the statement actually returns any row or not.

Execute:

```
SELECT table1.champ1 FROM schema.table1, schema.table2
```

Comment: It only works when I do not add "schema.table2" in FROM

Comment: Does the select statement returns any row?